# Concept of energy created from explosion

Tags: forces, energy, waves, explosions

I have seen people talking about energy of an explosion in movies. However, I did not understand what they mean. So I decided to do some thought experiment on it. I will lay down my thoughts and what I want from you is to assess credibility of my thoughts and notify me about mistakes in my thinking. My thinking purely relies on college level physics.

Here what I imagined:

Image an explosion took place in a deserted area. I image this explosion created a force field that propogates outward in every direction from origin of explosion. I image it like an travelling aperiodic finite-length  wave of force. Amplitude of this force wave decreases as you get away from it. As this hits you, it will exert force on you/does work on you and give you kinetic energy. Also this wave hits air molecules around it and gives them kinetic energy as well. Air molecules hit each other/vibrate and create sound that we will hear afterwards. Also moving air molecules that hits you will also give you kinetic energy(wind). Heat coming out of the explosion will be spread and absorbed by air molecules and objects around. What I am not sure is whether heat we absorve is coming from explosion only or energized air molecules hitting each other also creates friction which results in heat. Finally, sum of all the energy given away is simple energy of the explosion as I think. However, I have no idea on how much of this energy will be given as kinetic energy or termal energy etc. I assume it depends on the environment where the explosion takes place. I am also stuck on this that If explosion takes places in sky where there is no air/nothing, what will happen to heat, it will not be absorbed by anything. However, I know that that heat will not vanish but I do not know what will happen to it. Can you illuminate me on this thought experiment?

Comment: All the energy from the explosion will end up as heat,  by various mechanisms.

Comment: @nasu let's face it, in the big picture, all energy will end up as heat.

Comment: I thought I said the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take the case of a large high-explosive detonation.

In a very small volume you have a very large conversion of chemical potential energy into a correspondingly large amount of heat in a very short amount of time. Since power has time in the denominator, the power flow is very very large.

Some of that heat is promptly carried away as an intense flash of infrared and visible light that is strong enough to instantly ignite any combustible materials within a radius of order ~tens of meters.

The rest of that energy release is expressed as the kinetic energy contained in an expanding volume of extremely high-temperature gas, the products of the chemical reaction. Close to the explosion the expansion speed will be locally supersonic, forming a shock wave in which pressure, velocity and density are essentially discontinuous and in which there is heating of the shocked air by the violent compression in the shock front, but that shock heating is small compared to the heat release of the explosion itself.

The work done by the shock against the atmosphere is the integral of force times distance, both of which are functions of the blast radius. As that radius increases, the gas inside it is expanding and therefore cooling off, and the shock wave slows.

After ~tens of meters the shock becomes sonic and the maximum overpressure in the shock falls from its peak value in the supersonic case of ~6x ambient to a much smaller value, but which is still sufficient to break windows at a distance of order ~100 meters.

Several of these phenomena can be seen in the Beirut port explosion, of which good videos exist on youtube.